# How do I delete all pods related to all the namespace deployments with a single command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How do I delete all pods related to all the namespace's deployments with a single command? But not deleting the deployments themselves?

Please note that in other namespaces I have dozens of deployments, I need something generic to be able to capture all deployments at any case.

For example , I have the deployments below, I want to delete all of their pods (in this case 9 pods), without deleting the deployments.

I do not want to rollout restart (this changes the replica set IDs which I do not want), just deleting them to force the system to just recreate them with same number of replicas according to the deployment spec. Also scale to replicas 0 is not acceptable, as it is not one command, and then if I want to scale back, some of them have 1 some other 2 replicas etc.

```
kubectl get deployments.apps
NAME                                          READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
pm-bulk-reporter                              2/2     1            1           131d
pm-resource-monitor                           2/2     1            1           131d
sec-access-mgmt                               3/3     1            1           131d
sec-admin-user-management                     2/2     1            1           131d
```

Comment: Depending on your higher-level goal, do you either want to `kubectl rollout restart deployment` or `kubectl scale deployment --replicas=0`?

Comment: Rollout restart is not deleting and also changes the replicaset so I do not want it. Also scale deployment brings replicas to 0 , then I might want them to restart again and each deployment has different number of replicas.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the Pods?  Why is replacing the ReplicaSet a problem (you're not normally really aware of the ReplicaSet)?

Comment: Because I just want to delete the pods immediately without waiting for the rolling restart to complete. Also many times in rolling restart in latest Kubernetes versions, there is an old copy of the old replica set working. And also, according to the project, yes we do not want to change the replica set ID.

Comment: You can `kubectl delete pod -l <label>=<value>`, selecting the appropriate label and value to match the pods that belong to your deployment.

Comment: This sounds like you might need to write a script using the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) that can find the Pods in question and manually delete them.  If the identity (or existence) of the ReplicaSet matters to you then you may already have some experience with this.  The Pods' [owner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/owners-dependents/) will be the ReplicaSet, which in turn will be owned by the Deployment.

Comment: Could you explain why you want it to be a single command?

Answer (score 0):

To delete all the pods that belong to a Deployment, you can try something like:

```
kubectl -n my-namespace delete pods `kubectl -n my-namespace get pods -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.ownerReferences[0].kind=="ReplicaSet")].metadata.name}'`
```

Comment: I do not want to delete all the pods. Only the pods belonging to all the deployments. It is in the title. Also scaling up/down , as described already in the description is not desired solution, as for example afterwards take a lot of effort to scale back correctly each deployment. In my description for example, sec-access-mgmt has 3 pods.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that in the namespace you have also other pods, not only the deployments. I have updated the answer.